# Simplify an Algebraic Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

I would like to show the following algebraic equality holds for every $N \in \mathbb{N}$,

> $$
> \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^N \frac{N!}{k!(N-k)!}{{\theta^k}{{\left( {1 - \theta} \right)}^{N - k}}\log \left( {{{\left( {1 + x} \right)}^k}{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^{N - k}}} \right)}  = \theta \log \left( {1 + x} \right) + \left( {1 - \theta} \right)\log \left( {1 - x} \right)
> $$

My try is to use induction: assuming the above equality holds for $N$, and show $N+1$ also hold; however, I couldn't figure out a clever way to simplify the Left-Hand Side and stuck at very beginning.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Could the Binomial theorem help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Note first that $\log \left((1+x)^k(1-x)^{N-k}\right)=k\log (1+x)+(N-k)\log (1-x)$ so you can split the sum into two parts - one involving $\log (1+x)$ and the other involving $\log (1-x)$.

Treat these sums separately and note that the $\log$ terms don't now involve $k$ so can be taken outside the sums. The sums should then look rather like conventional binomial expansions which need to be adjusted a bit to give the result you want.

> Consider the binomial expansion of $\left(\theta+(1-\theta)\right)^N$. How can this be adapted to prove the result you want?